# Unable to kill zombie process with kill -9

Tags: linux, ubuntu

There are 2 zombie processes running in my server and I am unable to kill them with kill -9 command.

```
$ ps aux | awk '{ print $8 " " $2 }' | grep -w Z
```

**Output:**

Z 8511
Z 9002

Can someone please suggest me any other better way to kill them.

Thanks,

Sandeep.

Comment: Read more about [zombie processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process). You don't need and cannot kill them, becase they are *zombies*. You just should ensure someone `waitpid` for them.

Answer (score 11):

Basically - you can't.  And that's not necessarily a Bad Thing:

> http://www.linuxsa.org.au/tips/zombies.html
>
> Zombies are dead processes.  You cannot kill the dead.  All processes
>   eventually die, and when they do they become zombies.  They consume
>   almost no resources, which is to be expected because they are dead! 
>   The reason for zombies is so the zombie's parent (process) can
>   retrieve the zombie's exit status and resource usage statistics.  The
>   parent signals the operating system that it no longer needs the zombie
>   by using one of the wait() system calls.
>
> When a process dies, its child processes all become children of
>   process number 1, which is the init process.  Init is ``always''
>   waiting for children to die, so that they don't remain as zombies.
>
> If you have zombie processes it means those zombies have not been
>   waited for by their parent (look at PPID displayed by ps -l).  You
>   have three choices: Fix the parent process (make it wait); kill the
>   parent; or live with it.  Remember that living with it is not so hard
>   because zombies take up little more than one extra line in the output
>   of ps.

If you happen to know the parent, you can issue this command against the parent PID:

`kill -s SIGCHLD pid`